# Login screen fonts look weird

Tags: greeter, fonts

My login screen looks this ugly and I do not know how to fix it.

[image: Login Screen]

Yet, when I execute Pantheon-Greeter in terminal looks fine. Tried to reinstall lightdm and pantheon-greeter but did not work

Any suggestion?
Thanx